# I used a regular expression to restrict the numbers only between 3.00 to 100.00.But it was allowing the numbers between 100.01 to 100.99

Tags: regex

*I have a requirement to restrict the numbers between 3.00 to 100.00*
I used below expression

```
^([3-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

The issue with above expression is that, it's allowing 100.01 to 100.99,which should be restricted.It also allows 310 to 399,which needs to restricted.

I used another flavor of same expression

```
^([3-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100.00)+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Which was working as expected,but we need to enter 100.00 in to pass the regular expression instead of 100.

Is there any way,I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: What are the actual variations on `100` which should be allowed to pass?

Comment: I am sorry,I have tested with value 333,it's not restricting.
only 100.00 is allowed.Nothing else should be allowed.

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?:[1-9]\d|[3-9])(?:\.\d\d?)?|100(?:\.00?)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/U4TubO/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When alternating with the final `100`, use negative lookahead for `\.\d?[1-9]`, to ensure that the decimal places, if any, have only 0s.

Your first pattern can also match *many* repeated digits before the optional decimal (like 333 and 101010) due to the `+` at the end of the group, so best to remove the `+` if you only want to match between 3 and 100.

```
^(?:[3-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100(?!\.\d?[1-9]))(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/tJd3LQ/1

To permit leading zeros, add `0*` right after the `^`:

```
^0*(?:[3-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100(?!\.\d?[1-9]))(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
 ^^
```

Comment: @CodeManiac: I think someone went on a downvote spree for this question.

Comment: @npinti but this is not good :(  seeing good answers getting down votes.

Comment: This works fine,But it's not accepting values like 03 or 012 etc,I haven't added in the original question though,sorry for that.
@npinti answer also works apart from few edge cases.

Comment: @user3910075 If you want to permit leading zeros like that, replace the `^` at the start with `^0*`, no other changes needed, the zeros will be consumed if they exist, with no effect on the rest of the pattern

Answer (score 4):

**You can try this mate**

```
^(?:100(?:\.0+)?|(?:[3-9]|[1-9][0-9])(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNlOXA/5)

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor represent start of string.
- `(?:100(?:\.0+)?)` - This will match 100, 100.0, 100.00(any number of decimal zero's).
- `|` - Alternation this works same as Logical OR.
- `(?:[3-9]|[1-9][0-9])(?:\.\d{1,2})?)` - This will match any number from 3.00 to 99.99

> Suggestion

Always use non capturing group in case you're not using the group any where else again in your regex.

Comment: @revo Yeah i missed the trick.i have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: This will match `100.`, shouldn't `100(?:\.0*)?` be `100(?:\.0+)?`

Comment: @Liinux yes it's expected to match 100. ***Which was working as expected,but we need to enter 100.00 in to pass the regular expression instead of 100.*** op asked for it

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this: `^([3-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)+(\.\d{1,2})?$`, is that it *also* allows 100 in the first chunk (the chunk responsible for allowing whole numbers).

In your case, you would need to use something like so: `^100\.00$|([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])+(\.\d{1,2})?$` (Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/4BWNJu/1)).

This expression will either try to match `100.00` as a whole (which is your upper bound, or else, any number between `3.00` up till `99.99`.

Comment: It matches 100.000,actually it should not

Comment: @user3910075: You can try and use the following: `^100\.00$|([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])+(\.\d{1,2})?$`.

Comment: It works almost :) ,but it also matches `0120`,which is equal to 120

Comment: @user3910075: I have tried your two examples on the site I have linked, and it doesn't match, as expected

Comment: `0120` should be rejected,but it was accepted.@CeratainPerformance fixed it in his comment/answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this regex will work for You:

```
^([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?$|^100(\.0+)?$
```

Test:

```
$ cat numeric.txt
0.0
3
3.0
3.00
3.001
2.99
99.99
99.999
100
100.0
100.00
100.01
100.99

$ egrep '^([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?$|^100(\.0+)?$' numeric.txt
3
3.0
3.00
3.001
99.99
99.999
100
100.0
100.00
```